# R - How do I get the position of the final upper case character in the word having two upper case character in a vector of strings?

Tags: r

(Edited after **bgoldst**'s answer; thanks!)

Thanks for taking the time out to answer my question.

I have a vector of strings, each of which has at least one word with at least two upper case characters.

Here is an excerpt from my vector, for your reference:

```
[1] "Avg TSAvg TSThe average tariff score"
[2] "Customer SatisfactionCustomer SatisfactionA guide to how satisfied customers are"
[3] "ProspectsProspectsA guide to the profitability of segments"
[4] "QualityResearch QualityA measure of the quality of the research undertaken"
[5] "IntensityResearch IntensityA measure of the proportion of staff involved in research"
```

I need another vector with the position of the final upper case character of the first such word in each string. For the excerpt I shared, I'm looking to get the vector c(7, 22, 10, 8, 10).

The objective is to get a vector of sub-strings of all the original strings up to that position. For the excerpt I shared, I'm looking to get the vector `c("Avg TS", "Customer Satisfaction", "Prospects", "Quality", "Intensity")`.

P.S.: Tried to put together a number of regular expressions to get matches and match.lengths but have just not been able to crack this. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output doesn't quite match up with your verbal description. Note that for the first example string, the second capital is the `S`, and your expected output *includes* the `S`. But for all other example strings, your expected output *excludes* the second capital.

We can achieve the expected output by including the provision that all capitals starting from the second capital should be gobbled up, until we hit the last capital in the sequence, which should then be excluded. There may be zero such capitals gobbled up, such as in the latter four example strings, but there may be some, such as in the `Avg TS` example. Let's call this the **second capital extent**.

Note: I added an additional test case to cover the case of a second capital extent that is separated from the first capital in the word, and that contains more than one capital.

```
x <- c('Avg TSAvg TSThe average tariff score','Customer SatisfactionCustomer SatisfactionA guide to how satisfied customers are','ProspectsProspectsA guide to the profitability of segments','QualityResearch QualityA measure of the quality of the research undertaken','IntensityResearch IntensityA measure of the proportion of staff involved in research','Ab cDeFGh');
x;
## [1] "Avg TSAvg TSThe average tariff score"
## [2] "Customer SatisfactionCustomer SatisfactionA guide to how satisfied customers are"
## [3] "ProspectsProspectsA guide to the profitability of segments"
## [4] "QualityResearch QualityA measure of the quality of the research undertaken"
## [5] "IntensityResearch IntensityA measure of the proportion of staff involved in research"
## [6] "Ab cDeFGh"
sub(perl=T,'[A-Z]\\w*?[A-Z]*\\K[A-Z].*','',x);
## [1] "Avg TS" "Customer Satisfaction" "Prospects" "Quality" "Intensity" "Ab cDeF"
```

- The regex starts by matching the first capital with `[A-Z]`.
- It then skips over zero-or-more of any word characters non-greedily with `\w*?`.
- It then allows zero-or-more capitals to gobble up greedily with `[A-Z]*`. This implements my aforementioned provision.
- We then must hit the critical <s>second capital</s> final capital of the second capital extent with `[A-Z]`.
- Since we're calling `sub()` with the empty string as the replacement string, whatever is matched will be stripped from the string. Thus we can use the `\K` atom to effectively make everything to the left of the `\K` a positive lookbehind assertion, meaning it's not considered part of the final match extent and will be preserved. By placing the `\K` just after the `[A-Z]*` and just before the (final) `[A-Z]`, we effectively capture the entire string up to but not including the <s>second capital</s> final capital of the second capital extent.
- We also must be sure to include a trailing `.*` piece to match the rest of the string, which will then be stripped.

---

If you only want to apply the second capital extent provision when the extent is *not* separated from the first capital by non-capitals then we can change it to this:

```
sub(perl=T,'[A-Z]([A-Z]+|\\w*?)\\K[A-Z].*','',x);
## [1] "Avg TS" "Customer Satisfaction" "Prospects" "Quality" "Intensity" "Ab cDe"
```

In the above regex, I removed the `[A-Z]*` gobble and added a leading `[A-Z]+` alternation against the `\\w*?` piece, which basically means that we accept the second capital extent immediately following the first capital, but *only* if it occurs immediately following the first capital.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gregexpr` to get the numeric position.  We match a capital letter (`[A-Z]`) at the start of a word (`\\b`- for word boundary), followed by 0 or more lower case letters (`[a-z]*`) followed by "\K" (\K keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match) followed by an upper case letter (`[A-Z]`).

```
i1 <- gregexpr("\\b[A-Z][a-z]*\\K[A-Z]", v1, perl=TRUE)
i2 <- sapply(i1, `[`, 1)
i2
#[1]  6 22 10  8 10
```

Or using a simple regex with `str_locate`

```
library(stringr)
i2 <- str_locate(v1, "[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z]")[,2]
i2
#[1]  6 22 10  8 10
```

Applying it on 'v2'

```
i3 <- str_locate(v2, "[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z]")[,2]
i3
#[1]  6 22 10  8 10  7
```

and to get the sub strings,

```
sub("(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]$", "", substring(v1, 1, i2), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Avg TS"  "Customer Satisfaction" "Prospects" "Quality" Intensity"  

sub("(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]$", "", substring(v2, 1, i3), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Avg TS" "Customer Satisfaction" "Prospects" "Quality" "Intensity"  "Ab cDe"
```

Or without using any lookarounds

```
sub("^([A-Z][a-z]+\\b)?(\\s*([A-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]*)).*", "\\1\\2", v1)
#[1] "Avg TS" "Customer Satisfaction" "Prospects" "Quality" "Intensity"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c( "Avg TSAvg TSThe average tariff score", 
      "Customer SatisfactionCustomer SatisfactionA guide to how satisfied customers are",
 "ProspectsProspectsA guide to the profitability of segments",
 "QualityResearch QualityA measure of the quality of the research undertaken",
"IntensityResearch IntensityA measure of the proportion of staff involved in research")

v2 <- c(v1, "Ab cDeFGh")
```